# Detect timeout on azure function to reroute message to app service plan

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I've got an Azure function unziping archives on a consumption plan. Some of them happens to take more than 10min to unzip and can timeout. I'm thinking of having a separate app service plan where I would reroute the extraction when timing out on consumption plan.

How would you do that? a timer in the function? a catch timeout exception? Do you have a better suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: If you switch to a normal app service plan (not the consumption plan) for your functions app you will be able to extend the timeout. in the `host.json` file you can extend the timeout like that: {"functionTimeout": "00:15:00"}. See this article: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json

Comment: I know this, that's my plan but not for all the functions, I still want/need to benefit from the scalling offered by consumption plan. This is why I want to redirect only the archives timing out.

Comment: Create two functions apps with different service plan

Comment: Yep, but how do I detect timeouts on consumption plan to transfer them to app service plan? If possible I wanted some code to catch the timeout exception (if there is one) and queue a message with archive name to extract on a queue listenned by the service app one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those interested I ended adding my own timeout (few seconds earlier than Azure one) to the extract function, then rerouting to another queue handled by a service app plan than don't timeout.

Code :

```
using (var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource())
{
    try
    {
        // task completed within timeout
        timeoutCts.CancelAfter(590000);
        var counter = await ExtractArchiveAsync(archiveFullName, myBlob, timeoutCts.Token);
        log.Info($"Extracted : { counter.GetCurrentCount() }");
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // timeout logic
        log.Info($"Function timedout, redirected to long queue");
        var queue = StorageService.GetCloudQueueReference("ArchiveToExtractQueueTimedOut");
        await queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(archiveFullName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer requires ExtractArchiveAsync() to throw the OperationCanceledException. While this can work, I had a different usecase that might be useful to others finding this thread:

```
private static async Task ExecuteWithTimeout(Func<Task> action, int timeout)
{
      Task task = action();
      if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task)
      {
          await task;
      }
      else
      {
          throw new TimeoutException("Timeout after " + timeout + " milliseconds");
      }
}
```