# Timeout value of 00:05:00 was exceeded by function in azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am running an azure function with basic plan in portal. I am getting this timeout error and my function is not running because of this reason. How I can resolve this issue

[image: See the error]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Azure Functions are now allowed to run upto 10 minutes. You need to change the "functionTimeout" value in host.json file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout

Also, please check a similar question posted on SO:
[Azure Functions timeout for Consumption plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358151/azure-functions-timeout-for-consumption-plan)

Comment: If even 10 minutes are too short for your jobs, consider using the "Durable Functions" framework, which lets you split up your jobs into smaller junks.

Comment: In short: Add `"functionTimeout": "00:10:00"` to your host.json file